# Reverse Colors on Google Doc for printing

Tags: google-docs

There may be a simple answer but is there a quick way to reverse colors on google docs, just for printing?

I like having our background of the doc blue and the text white for the view mode on the screen, but if someone goes to print that is a lot of blue ink, is there a fast way to change it --- not copying and pasting into a new doc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Google Docs doesn't have the option of reversing the colors in the document when trying to print it.

What you can do instead is to make a copy of the original document and then modify it to your liking so it is suitable for printing. In this way you will have two copies of the document -  one for the **viewing mode** and one for the **printing mode**.

Answer (score 0):

go to format -> images -> image options -> recolor select negative